# How to run parallel tasks in sequence?

Tags: python, airflow-2.x

I've a dag in below format

[image]

As you can see, there are parallel tasks from `weather` to `end`, when I trigger this dag, it runs all `weather to end` flows in parallel.

But is there any way I could trigger, `weather to end` flow one by one ?

Once, first flow of `weather to end` is finished, then run the second `weather to end` and so on..

```
start = DummyOperator(task_id='start')
finish = DummyOperator(task_id='finish', dag=dag, trigger_rule=TriggerRule.NONE_FAILED)


    def running_tasks():
        print("boom")


    weather = {'summers', 'winters', 'spring'}

    with TaskGroup(group_id='compute') as compute:
        w = DummyOperator(task_id='weather', dag=dag)
        end = DummyOperator(task_id='weather_end', dag=dag)

        with TaskGroup(group_id='weather_based_tasks') as weather_based_tasks:
            for name in weather:
                with TaskGroup(group_id=name, tooltip=name) as weather_name:
                    weather_specific = PythonOperator(dag=dag,
                                                      task_id=name,
                                                      python_callable=running_tasks,
                                                      pool="weather_pool"
                                                      )

                    with TaskGroup(group_id='tasks', tooltip='tasks') as task_name:

                        task01 = DummyOperator(task_id='task_01')
                        task02 = DummyOperator(task_id='task_02')

                        [task01, task02]

                        w >> weather_specific >> task_name >> end

    start >> compute >> finish
```

Thanks

Comment: Sharing a working code example would be appreciated.

Comment: @Cow, updated with code, please check now

Answer (score 0):

You can use threading library,

```
from threading import Thread

def task1():
    return
def task2():
    return
...
t1 = Thread(target=task1) # you can add arguments into Thread()
t2 = Thread(target=task2)
...
t1.run()
t2.run()
...
# When your tasks finished you can use join to close threads
t1.join()
t2.join()
...
```

this example should help you to get an idea to do tasks in the same time

Comment: but how it will manage the completion state, because next seq should start once last is finished